# Nginx proxy_pass long directive

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, regex, proxypass

i want to do proxy_pass

from `https://foo.bar/api/v1/users/{userId}/store/{storeCode}/status` to `https://bar.foo/api/v1/users/{userId}/store/{storeCode}/status`

and also

from `https://foo.bar/api/v1/users/{userId}/opendate` to `https://bar.foo/api/v1/users/{userId}/opendate`

the different with that 2 links are http method that use to access, later we will limit access with limit_except, but now i want to proxy_pass the request first.

i've made a configuration like this

```
location /api/v1/users/[0-9a-z]+/store {
    proxy_pass https://bar.foo/api/v1/users/[0-9a-z]+/store;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}


location /api/v1/users/[0-9a-z]+/opendate {
    proxy_pass https://bar.foo/api/v1/users/[0-9a-z]+/opendate;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
    proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

but i still don't get my server proxying the request.
is there anyone know how to proxy_pass long directive location with some regex in nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is a regular expression, you are using the wrong syntax for the `location` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You only need to give `proxy_pass` a URI part, if the URI is changed before passing upstream. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/users/[0-9a-z]+/store {
    proxy_pass https://bar.foo;
    ...
}
```

Comment: its work for me. thank you so much